# Guide positions and colors not being saved in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, svg

I have a two-part question about guides in Inkscape. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and I have Inkscape 0.91.

1. I noticed that in documents where I've switched the default units to pixels instead of mm (File>Document Properties>Units), guide positions do not persist after saving, closing, and reopening.

The number of guides and their angle is saved, but they all begin at the origin (bottom left corner of the document) and pile up on top of each other.

Has anyone else encountered this issue, and is there any solution other than using mm as the default unit in all documents?

I found a related [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1373311) for version 0.92 that is marked as resolved. However, this fix is for a newer version than the one I have. It is possible to upgrade to 0.92 with Ubuntu 16.04 using a PPA but I'm hesitant to install an unofficial distribution without making sure it won't bring any unwanted problems along with it.

2. Regardless of what the default units are, any guide colors I assign disappear when I reopen a saved document. Can anyone suggest a way to troubleshoot this, or explain why this happens?

## UPDATE:

I installed Inkscape 0.92 using the PPA, and so far it hasn't caused any problems for me.

However, guide positions and colors are STILL not being saved when the document unit is px.

Answer (score 2):

As you have already written, people have encountered the issue, the bug has been reported, and it has been fixed.

The ppa is not unofficial, it is the official source for up-to-date Inkscape versions. See Inkscape website: http://inkscape.org/releases/

The guide colors are also now saved.

You can read the release notes for [0.92](https://inkscape.org/release/0.92/), [0.92.1](https://inkscape.org/release/0.92.1/), [0.92.2](https://inkscape.org/release/0.92.2/) and [0.92.3](https://inkscape.org/release/0.92.3/) to find out what is new.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should have been more clear--while the PPA may be stable, it's not the release in the main Ubuntu Xenial repository.

Comment: Yes, that's true. However, if you have sudo or root access to on your computer, you can install it. Or you could even use the snap package of Inkscape, but that's quite restrictive as far as access to other parts of the system is concerned, unfortunately - and intentionally (e.g. AFAIK, it doesn't see all fonts, has an ugly interface that doesn't adapt to your theme, it can't access files outside your home folder per default, ...).